# (WPF) Animate ListView item move

Tags: wpf, listview, animation

I would like to have an animation when an item in ListView changes position, so it would slowly move to the new position. Either in a template or in code.
I've tried descending from a (Virtualizing)StackPanel and overriding ArrangeOverride to reposition and animate the items. the problem is that I don't know at what position the item was 'before' the update so I could transition to the new position nicely. I tried checking the TranslateTransform of the item, storing  in a dictionary, overriding OnItemChanged and storing OldPosition/Position .. but none of there work because it seems the items are always recreated (from template).

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Maybe this article by Matthias Shapiro would help: [How To Create An Animated ScrollViewer (or ListBox) in WPF](http://www.designersilverlight.com/2009/05/06/how-to-create-an-animated-scrollviewer-or-listbox-in-wpf/)

Answer (score 8):

Use FluidMoveBehavior behaviour , it will make you life lot easier.

you can apply this to any itemscontrol in the following manner

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelTemplate">
            <WrapPanel>
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <il:FluidMoveBehavior AppliesTo="Children" Duration="00:00:00.75"/>
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </WrapPanel>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

you can find this behaviour in the Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll that is installed along with Blend 3

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation of FluidMoveBehavior? I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Limited class documentation can be found in the Expression Blend SDK Userguide that is installed along with Blend 3

Comment: thanks for all answers .. this method with behaviors looks nice, but the problem is that all of the items are recreated and thus all are animated into position (from the top). same problem applies to all other solutions.
I will look into using a DataGrid instead as it seems to have a few other things I would like.

Comment: Could always wait till after your List is populated before attaching the behavior

Answer (score 1):

In fact this problem was perfectly solved by Dan Crevier back in 2006. Check out his [PanelLayoutAnimator](http://blogs.msdn.com/dancre/archive/2006/03/04/543854.aspx) class.

Comment: +1.  I just checked this article out -- it involves a single class, the code sample was easy to understand, using it only involves adding a single attribute to your XAML and the result looks good.  Recommended.

Comment: The page does not exist anymore. It leads to just their blog